# Concept of Hysteresis and Threshold point in Schmitt Trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger, positive-feedback

[image]

I understand the concept of Schmitt Trigger where there is 2 transition threshold points so that input changing between the hysteresis would not create output transitions . The very first observation that I made in this design requirement is the overlap/ hysteresis is between +1 and -1, so shouldn't the threshold be +1 and -1. So can threshold be +2 and -2 as in the options ? Are there more points to consider while deciding threshold ? Can I say as a thumbrule that the overlapping segment of inputs should always be included in the hysterisis that is here between +1 and -1, anything more is always good but that should always be less than the Maximum and minimum that is here +7 and -7?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the noise goes to -1V when the pulse is in a positive phase and to +1V when the pulse is in the negative phase.

Choosing +/- 1V as thresholds could cause the noise to change the output state *when it should not* because the noise is reaching the switching threshold. For the +/- 0.5V option, the noise would *definitely* cause unintended switching.

Therefore +/- 0.5V is not a good option.

As the total signal varies between +7V and -7V, the +/- 8V option would never change the output state.

The +/-2V option gives an extra 1V of [noise immunity](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423146/noise-immunity-and-noise-margin) and (for the given task) would be suitable thresholds.

For the general case, the thresholds should also be below the *noise free* input signal; as we usually protect against noise *up to* a certain level, a noise free input should be part of the calculation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Can I say as a thumbrule that the overlapping segment of inputs should always be included in the hysterisis that is here between +1 and -1, anything more is always good but that should always be less than the Maximum and minimum that is here +7 and -7?

Comment: @Fawaz; the maximum should really be less than the noise free amplitude of the signal in general (< +/- 3V in this case); usually we are dealing with noise *up to* a certain level so a noise free input should also be considered for the general case.